# connect to testcontainer from springboot without @DynamicPropertySource

Tags: spring-boot, testcontainers

i am trying to make testing with test container from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3eQCIWLYOw)

there we try to make a container and make springboot connect to it with @DynamicPropertySource.

```
 @Container
private static PostgreSQLContainer container = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:12.9");

@DynamicPropertySource
public static void overrideProps(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry){
    registry.add("jdbc.connectionString", container::getJdbcUrl);
    registry.add("jdbc.username", container::getUsername);
    registry.add("jdbc.password", container::getPassword);
}
```

but i am using springboot 2.1.4, there for i can not use @DynamicPropertySource.
is there a way to change the application.property at runtime so it can use port that the container randomly created?

i've tried to change may jdbc.connectionString to jdbc:tc:postgresql:12.9:///databasename but i got error and i don't think that is correct way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The testcontainers specific JDBC URL should work, but you need to provide one additional property if you use SpringBoot versions before `2.3.0` (as mentioned in the [docs](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/)):

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:tc:postgresql:12.9:///databasename
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver
```

Imho it's the easiest (and recommended) approach.

Alternatively, you can find an example of how to adjust application properties at runtime without `@DynamicPropertySource` in this [spring article](https://spring.io/blog/2020/03/27/dynamicpropertysource-in-spring-framework-5-2-5-and-spring-boot-2-2-6):

```java
@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ExampleIntegrationTests.Initializer.class)
class ExampleIntegrationTests {

    @Container
    static Neo4jContainer<?> neo4j = new Neo4jContainer<>();

    static class Initializer implements
            ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
            TestPropertyValues.of("spring.data.neo4j.uri=" + neo4j.getBoltUrl())
                    .applyTo(context.getEnvironment());
        }

    }

}
```